# REWRITE: Navlinks Image Button Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had help with my previous question to be able to create changing navlinks with my navbar with JavaScript. Now I need to make the buttons be created automatically within the same JavaScript. This is what I had, this is what the code creates, with CSS and html output. http://jsfiddle.net/k35wawyg/2/

## What Should Happen

What should happen is the buttons appear above each other in the top right, but it seems that it doesn't work. Also, the buttons should be linked with the JavaScript src that *would* be inside the HTML with

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="navlinks">
        <div id="output2">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="nav.js">
</div>
```

## What Actually Happens

As you can see in the JSFiddle, they are under the NavBar, across from each other, and clicking it will make it output a console error with:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: execFunction() is not defined`

Please help. I rewrote the question due to a JSFIDDLE request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had a number of problems in your fragment.  I have modified the code and here is a new jsFiddle that now seems to work.  Because there were so many things I changed, I can't list them here but if you compare the new code to your existing code, hopefully it should become clear.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/k35wawyg/3/)

Probably the biggest change was the way that the functions were invoked:

```
<a onclick="execFunction2();">
```

Comment: The problem with that is the buttons disappear after clicking?

Comment: I had understood that your original question was the uncaught exception and that has (apparently) been resolved in the code change.  It sounds like you have a brand new question?

Comment: I do, but I apparently can only post every 90 minutes.

Comment: Sorry you have to wait but there will always be good folks here happy to assist with the questions when you do get to post again.  Maybe take the time to write your question as clearly as possible in a wordprocessor so that when it is time to post again, you have an AWESOME question ready to be read?